# Player hitting bottom of tile when beside it?

Tags: collision-detection, javascript

So my player checks if it is colliding with tiles, and it works pretty good. However, when the player is against a wall, moving upwards and sideways, it detects it as hitting the bottom of the wall since the player checks for up and down collision first. How do I prevent this? Maybe there is another collision method I could use? Thanks in advance

[image: The player is moving upwards and sideways, hitting the bottom]

Here's the collision code:

```
player.checkCollision = function (obj) {

            const top = obj.y - this.h;
            const bottom = obj.y + obj.h;

            const left = obj.x - this.w;
            const right = obj.x + obj.w;

            if (this.x > left && this.x < right) {

                if (this.y >= top && this.y - this.vel.y <= top) {

                    this.y = top;
                    this.vel.y = 0;

                    return 1;

                }
                if (this.y <= bottom && this.y - this.vel.y >= bottom) {

                    this.y = bottom;
                    this.vel.y = 0;

                    return 1;

                }   

            }
            if (this.y > top && this.y < bottom) {

                if (this.x >= left && this.x - this.vel.x <= left) {

                    this.x = left;
                    this.vel.x = 0;

                    return 1;

                }
                if (this.x <= right && this.x - this.vel.x >= right) {

                    this.x = right;
                    this.vel.x = 0;

                    return 1;

                }   

            }

            return 0;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So is the problem that when the player is moving in both directions at the same time a collision is detected and the player stops moving?

You can either redo the whole collision detection function which probably isn't a bad idea or simply try moving in each direction separately and see if that works.